# Create a linq query that get all elements that are not referenced in an aditonal table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hi I have to create a select query using linq and things are not going as I expected.Here is what I am tying to achieve:

This is my databse diagram I am using Entity Framework database first model:
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
  public IEnumerable<FriendModel> GetSuggestedFriends(int userId, int numberOfFriendsToSkip,
        int numberOfFriendsToGet)
    {
           var currentUser = dbContext.AspNetUsers.First(x => x.Id.Equals(userId));

        var friendsList = (from user in dbContext.AspNetUsers
                           from friend in user.Friends1
                           from currentUserFriend in currentUser.Friends1
                           where user.Id != currentUser.Id && user.Id != currentUserFriend.UserFriendId
                           select new FriendModel
                           {
                               AvatarId = user.AvatarId,
                               FirstName = user.FirstName,
                               LastName = user.LastName,
                               UserId = user.Id
                           }).ToList();


        return friendsList;
    }
```

What I wanted to say here get me all the users in the db that are not the current user and that the current user does not have that user as a friend.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? My query seems to return zero elements when it should return 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//select all users where the id is not the current id and the id is not any of the ids of the users friends

```
IQueryable<User> users = context.Users;

var results = users.Where(x => x.Id != userId &&
                                           !users.Where(v => v.Id == userId)
                                                 .SelectMany(v => v.Friends.Select(d => d.Id))
                                                 .Any(e => e == x.Id))
                                                 .Select(x=>new
                                                                {
                                                                    //your projection
                                                                })
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

Not particularly efficient but if you only have a few records this should be effective:

```
var friendsList = dbContext.AspNetUsers
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(u.Id != currentUserId && !u.Friends
                                                     .Select(f=>f.UserFriendId)
                                                     .AsEnumerable()
                                                     .Contains(currentUserId))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I think this is OK, but why `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: I dont think you can use that nested `Contains()` query in an `IQueryable` but I'm prepared to be wrong! ;-)

Comment: Oh, that should be alright. The `AsEnumerable()` makes it very inefficient (it draws everything into memory before filtering).

Comment: Indeed, that's why I qualified it with "Not particularly efficient but if you only have a few records..."